# Why "create topic" option is disabled on azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-servicebus-topics

can someone please help me understand why the "Create Topic" option is disabled on Azure portal? I am on a free trial and can create/use queue properly. Now I need to use Topic/Subscription but not able to create a topic. Please see below screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Navigate to `Scale` in the portal, change `messaging tier` to `Standard`, it will be able.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you hit the bulls eye, thanks a lot. Just a question, will updating from Basic to Standard affect my azure subscription (e.g billing or something else?) as I am using a free trial for now.

Comment: @V.P.Verma I think yes, they have different prices, https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7RS5.png, refer to : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/

Comment: As always, Azure Portal is constantly evolving. Settings/Scale seems to be removed. Scaling option can be done from Overview.

Answer (score 6):

Topics are only available in Standard an Premium pricing tiers of an Azure Service Bus namespace, not the Basic tier.

In the *Overview* section of the Azure Service Bus namespace, click on *Pricing Tier: Basic*, and change it to Standard (or Premium).

NOTE: this change will have an effect on cost.

[image: Azure Service Bus Tier]

This answer is based on Joy's answer above, but with the updated user interface in the Azure Portal.

Comment: Given that the Portal UI is now different this answer should now be the correct/accepted one.